# eval variable as command in shell script

Tags: command-line, bash

I have command

`docker container exec -it man docker service ps $1 --no-trunc --filter "desired-state=running" --format "docker container exec -it {{.Node}} docker container exec -it {{.Name}}.{{.ID}} bash"`

and it returns the strings like this in stdout

`docker container exec -it 13247a1833e9 docker container exec -it django_python.yhb1osnt1wn32hbkixhf50r38.hzsgyxbdkpitrsa6fdjiyi4qu bash`

now I want to exec this.

my script is here,

```
msg=`docker container exec -it man docker service ps $1 --no-trunc --filter "desired-state=running" --format "docker container exec -it {{.Node}} docker container exec -it {{.Name}}.{{.ID}} bash"`

eval ${msg}
```

but it returns the error

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\\r\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

How can I solve this??

Comment: Why `eval $msg`? `$msg` should be enough.

Comment: it shows the same error `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\\r\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

Comment: Are you on Windows? This CR character (`\\r`) is suspicious....

Comment: Also if I read it correctly the command you have is really trying to execute a `docker exec` inside another `docker exec`? What are you trying to do? Looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Maybe ask about your root problem in another question?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am trying to reach the `docker container` working on another `docker container` from localhost.( I am simulating the network by `docker dind` and launch docker on it for multi server development environment).

Comment: Can't be done that way... that would mean that any container could do anything to other containers, that would be a major security issue... And think about it; you would have a container with a `docker` command, that would talk to a docker service (where does that one run, container? host? how to connect to it?)? Containers are not VMs.